update a column of a dataframe using mutate and case_when
I have this sample data frame
df<-data.frame(old_farm=c("Yes", "Yes","Yes", "No", "No", "No" , NA ),
env_year=c(2011, 2020,2019,2010,2010,2010, NA),
global_M=c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes","Yes", "No", NA ),
audit_year=c(2014, NA,NA,2010,NA,NA,NA),
Situation=c("New costat 2011, Closed antex 2014",
   "New costat 2020",
 "New costat 2019",
"Closed antex 2010",
"missing entry",
"Full exit", "Not at all"))

df
  old_farm env_year global_M audit_year                          Situation
1      Yes     2011      Yes       2014 New costat 2011, Closed antex 2014
2      Yes     2020      Yes         NA                    New costat 2020
3      Yes     2019       No         NA                    New costat 2019
4       No     2010      Yes       2010                  Closed antex 2010
5       No     2010      Yes         NA                      missing entry
6       No     2010       No         NA                          Full exit
7     <NA>       NA     <NA>         NA                         Not at all

I want to update the last column "Situation". In particular,

if old_farm == "Yes" & global_M == "Yes" & !is.na(audit_year), then I want to have  in the Situation column: "New costat xa", env_year, "Closed antex xa", audit_year; where the env_year and audit_year are the  years from  the corresponding columns.
and if old_farm == "No" & global_M == "Yes" & !is.na(audit_year), then I want to have in the last column "Closed antex xa",  audit_year, where the  audit_year is the  year from  the corresponding column.

So I want to have
df_n<-data.frame(old_farm=c("Yes", "Yes","Yes", "No", "No", "No" , NA ),
env_year=c(2011, 2020,2019,2010,2010,2010, NA),
global_M=c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes","Yes", "No", NA ),
audit_year=c(2014, NA,NA,2010,NA,NA,NA),
Situation=c("New costat xa2011, Closed antex xa2014",
   "New costat 2020",
 "New costat 2019",
"Closed antex xa2010",
"missing entry",
"Full exit", "Not at all"))


df_n
 old_farm env_year global_M audit_year                              Situation
1      Yes     2011      Yes       2014 New costat xa2011, Closed antex xa2014
2      Yes     2020      Yes         NA                        New costat 2020
3      Yes     2019       No         NA                        New costat 2019
4       No     2010      Yes       2010                    Closed antex xa2010
5       No     2010      Yes         NA                          missing entry
6       No     2010       No         NA                              Full exit
7     <NA>       NA     <NA>         NA                             Not at all

So I executed these three alternative commands but none of them works
    library(dplyr)
    
   
 df %>%
  mutate(
Situation = case_when(
    old_farm == "Yes" & global_M == "Yes" & !is.na(audit_year) ~
      paste0("New costat xa", env_year, ", Closed antex xa", audit_year),
old_farm == "No" & global_M == "Yes" & !is.na(audit_year) ~
      paste0("Closed antex xa",  audit_year)      ))
 


 df %>%
  mutate(across("Situation") , case_when(
    old_farm == "Yes" & global_M == "Yes" & !is.na(audit_year) ~
      paste0("New costat xa", env_year, ", Closed antex xa", audit_year) ,
old_farm == "No" & global_M == "Yes" & !is.na(audit_year) ~
      paste0("Closed antex xa",  audit_year)   ))


df %>%
  mutate_at("Situation",~ case_when(
    old_farm == "Yes" & global_M == "Yes" & !is.na(audit_year) ~
      paste0("New costat xa", env_year, ", Closed antex xa", audit_year),
old_farm == "No" & global_M == "Yes" & !is.na(audit_year) ~
      paste0("Closed antex xa",  audit_year)  ))

I am not sure where the mistake is. My real data set contains thousands of rows.

Without room to improve there's nothing wrong with your approach. Maybe you just missed to use .default
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Situation = 
    case_when(
      old_farm == "Yes" & global_M == "Yes" & !is.na(audit_year) ~ 
        paste0("New costat xa", env_year, ", Closed antex xa", audit_year), 
      old_farm == "No" & global_M == "Yes" & !is.na(audit_year) ~ 
        paste0("Closed antex xa", audit_year), .default = Situation))
  old_farm env_year global_M audit_year                              Situation
1      Yes     2011      Yes       2014 New costat xa2011, Closed antex xa2014
2      Yes     2020      Yes         NA                        New costat 2020
3      Yes     2019       No         NA                        New costat 2019
4       No     2010      Yes       2010                    Closed antex xa2010
5       No     2010      Yes         NA                          missing entry
6       No     2010       No         NA                              Full exit
7     <NA>       NA     <NA>         NA                             Not at all


Thank you but this does not help a lot. I have more compicated replacements to do and gsub is not very useful. As I mentioned, what I wrote is a sample/example as my  real data set contains thousands of rows and many replacements

But it looks like the proposed solution gives the results you are looking for, so it is not clear what the problem is. Note that you may get the same results by adding .default = Situation in the first of the codes you attempted.

.default=Situation. That worked!  This is what I was looking for!. That's why my codes did not worked! Thank you very much!!
